# Does volo support enterprise Github?

Tags: javascript, dependency-management, volojs

We're trying to use Volo as a front end dependency manager, but a lot of our repositories reside on our enterprise Github server.

I can't find any documentation about Volo supporting it, outside of linking to raw files served via https.

Does Volo have support for enterprise Github or should we move to something else?

Things that I've tried-

`volo add https://github.domain.com/org/repo/master/dist/output.zip`

^ added the zip itself, but it should be unpacked, also this doesn't allow us to use tags or any sort of smart version management.

`volo add git@github.domain.com:org/repo#1.0.0`

^ fails with `Do not have a volo resolver for scheme: git@` message.

`volo add ssh://git@github.domain.com:org/repo#1.0.0`

^ fails with `Do not have a volo resolver for scheme: ssh:` message.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/volojs/volo/wiki/Create-templates) are some documented examples.

Comment: I don't think this is the right question for stack overflow...

Comment: Those are good examples of creating a project from templates, but I need to actually add dependencies from a private enterprise github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After forking Volo and playing with the code a bit I've found that it doesn't support Enterprise GitHub.

It's being worked on though:

https://github.com/volojs/volo/pull/181